# How to compute the derivative of $ \frac{\operatorname{diag}(\lambda) \cdot [e^{z_j}]}{\lambda^T \cdot [e^{z_j}]}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R^n$ be a constant. For convenience, we adopt the writing $z = [z_j]$ for $z \in \mathbb R^n$. After some computation, I obtain a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ such that

$$f(z) = \frac{\operatorname{diag}(\lambda) \cdot [e^{z_j}]}{\lambda^T \cdot [e^{z_j}]}.$$

My goal is to compute $\partial_z f$ in a neat way by using matrix calculus. I consulted the textbook [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), but could not find relevant formula.

Could you please elaborate on how to compute $\partial_z f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
ease of typing, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
L &= \D(\lambda), \quad
y &= \exp(z), \quad
Y &= \D(y) \quad\implies\quad dy=Y\,dz \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables, then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= \frac{Ly}{\lambda^Ty} \\
df &= \frac{L\,dy}{\lambda^Ty} - \frac{Ly\,(\lambda^Tdy)}{(\lambda^Ty)^2} \\
  &= \frac{L\,dy}{\lambda^Ty} - \frac{f\lambda^Tdy}{\lambda^Ty} \\
  &= \left(\frac{L-f\lambda^T}{\lambda^Ty}\right)dy \\
  &= \left(\frac{L-f\lambda^T}{\lambda^Ty}\right)Y\,dz \\
\p{f}{z}
  &= \left(\frac{L-f\lambda^T}{\lambda^Ty}\right)Y \\
}$$

Comment: It's very neat. Could you please have a look at this related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4127363/how-to-use-matrix-calculus-to-compute-the-derivative-of-x-mapsto-left-frac)?

Comment: @Akira Setting $L=I$ will solve the related question.

Comment: Oh my bad ^^ Thank you so much for your help!